# Concatenate foreign key fields with delimiter Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-annotate, django-aggregation

Lets say I have 2 models with a foreign key relation which are used to bundle books:

```
class Bundle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    bundle = models.ForeignKey(Bundle)
```

we'll identify the bundles by concatenating the ISBN numbers with the delimiter like so:

```
123456788 & 123456789
```

To further export a list of available bundles for further processing we need that number.

I'm aware I could use:

```
for bundle in Bundle.objects.all():
    complex_isbn = ' & '.join(bundle.book_set.all().values_list('isbn', flat=True))
```

But this would just be too slow for the real-world purpose.
Is there a way I could use annotate to accomplish this?  If so, how?  I'm struggling to find my way through the docs on how to accomplish concatenating multiple foreign key entries.

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`StringAgg`** aggregate function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg), which is only available for PostgreSQL. You thus can annotate the `Bundle`s with the complex ISBN:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg

Bundle.objects.annotate(
    complex_isbn=StringAgg('isbn', delimiter=' & ')
)
```

The `Bundle`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.complex_isbn`.